# How to distinguish UITextFields in delegate methods?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uitextfield

I have the following code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    // MARK: Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var layersTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var innerShapeTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var outerShapeTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        layersTextField.delegate = self
        innerShapeTextField.delegate = self
        outerShapeTextField.delegate = self
    }

    // MARK: UITextFieldDelegate
    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        // do something
    }

}
```

Now in `textFieldDidEndEditing(_:)` I would like to do something, dependent on which `UITextField` called this method.
Is there any way to distinguish, which `UITextField` did this? Is there some kind of ID or identifier I can set on the `UITextField`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make this determination using one of two approaches: outlets or tags. For the outlet approach, declare an outlet instance variable (using the `IBOutlet` keyword) and then make an outlet connection. In your delegation method, test whether the passed-in text object is the same object referenced by the outlet, using pointer comparison.
For example, say you declare and connect an outlet named `SSN`. Your code might look something like [Listing 3-1](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/ManageTextFieldTextViews/ManageTextFieldTextViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH10-SW1):

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField == SSN) {
        // ...
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

// Translated to Swift:

func textFieldShouldEndEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField === SSN {
        // ...
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check by the name of the next filed. `if textField == layersTextField { //do what you want }` and you can do that for any text field you need a specific action for.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an IBAction instead:

[image]